# How to get last occurrences in SQLAlchemy and postgresql database?

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

How to query postgres database to get grouped result with last occurrence?

I have a table like this one:

```
id | emp_id | hours
1  | 1      | 8
2  | 1      | 6
3  | 2      | 6
4  | 2      | 3
5  | 1      | 5
```

I want to receive below result:

```
emp_id | hours
1      | 5
2      | 3
```

I want it to be ordered descending by id and get last value for each employee.

Comment: Could you please post your try, so that we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use some group by and do something like :

```
from sqlalchemy import func
session.query(Table.col_emp_id,func.max(Table.col_hour)).group_by(Table.col_emp_id).all()
```

I'm not an expert, just a clue

Answer (score 0):

The script below can give you the expected result :

```html
select emp_id,hours 
from (
select *, row_number() over(partition by emp_id order by id desc) as rank
from <your_table>
)tab
where tab.rank=1
```